# How to make an array in struct to use it in a loop?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, structure

I have 34 products in a CSV file and I want to use each of them in an HTML file. For this purpose, I need an array key so that I can use a value in an HTML file one by one.

**Problem**

- Whenever I execute this code, it prints only the last product name.
- I don't know how to make an array in a struct so that I can use it as a key using the for-loop.

**Code**

```
type List struct {
    ProductsList string
}

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var user List
    for i := 0; i < 34; i++ {
        user = List{
            ProductsList: products.AccessData(i),
        }
    }
    HomeTmpl.Execute(w, user)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make `ProductsList` a slice(fancy array) by delaring it like this `[]string`. We can then use the `append` function to add elements to the end of the slice. This will make a slice where the index of the slice matches `i`.

```
type List struct {
    ProductsList []string
}

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var user List
    for i := 0; i < 34; i++ {
        user.ProductsList = append(user.ProductsList, products.AccessData(i))
    }
    HomeTmpl.Execute(w, user)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, caveman! But how can I show a specific product in an HTML file. I wrote `<h1>{{ (index . 0).ProductsList }}</h1>` but it showed me nothing in the browser.

Comment: `Execute` should return an error explaining what is wrong, always make sure to check error returns. In this case you are trying to access an index of `List` but list is not a slice. You want to access `List.ProductsList` like so: `<h1>{{ (index .ProductsList 0) }}</h1>`

Comment: Thank you, caveman! `<h1>{{ (index .ProductsList 0) }}</h1>`. This code worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

I changed ProductList properties to slice string

```
type List struct {
    ProductsList []string
}

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    AllData := []string{}

    for i := 0; i < 34; i++ {
        AllData = append(AllData, products.AccessData(i))
    }

    user := List{ ProductsList: AllData }
    // user.ProducList = ["yourdata","hello","example","and more"]

    HomeTmpl.Execute(w, user)
}
```

Comment: You need: `AllData = append(AllData, products.AccessData(i))` otherwise the slice will not grow across iterations.

Comment: okey i forget todo that